# Using Ternary Operator in OrderBy Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, conditional-operator

I've seen code similar to the following:

`collection.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate == null ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(x => x.CreatedDate).To list();`

I have Googled and searched this site and I can't find any explanation for what this does. Normally I order by a field in the collection by property name.

Can someone please explain to me what this does in plain English. I understand the ternary to mean if StartDate is null, order by 0, else order by 1. That doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's essentially ordering by `CreatedDate`, but in two groups.  First the group where `StartDate` is `null`, then the group where `StartDate` is not `null`.

This creates two "groups":

```
.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate == null ? 0 : 1)
```

So first you have all records where `StartDate` is `null`, followed by all records where it's not `null`.  Then the secondary order within each "group" is by `CreatedDate`:

```
.ThenBy(x => x.CreatedDate)
```

So in plain English it might be described as:

> Show me all records with no `StartDate`, sorted by `CreatedDate`, followed by all records with a `StartDate`, sorted by `CreatedDate`.

Comment: Ok, thank you David. That makes sense. I will be able to accept your answer in about 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

`.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate == null ? 0 : 1)` will put items without `StartDate` as first in the output basically "splitting" the set in two "groups" and then for every "group" additional sorting by `CreatedDate` is applied via `.ThenBy(x => x.CreatedDate)`.

Some extra notes - from [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#remarks) docs:

> By definition, any object compares greater than (or follows) `null`, and two null references compare equal to each other.

But if you are actually querying a database - order of `null`'s is not standardized and is database depended ([for example](https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-order-rows-with-nulls/#:%7E:text=How%20Are%20NULLs%20Sorted%20by,last%20in%20the%20result%20set.), also AFAIK EF Core for instance usually tries to translate such things so they are consistent with LINQ-to-Objects/runtime behaviour) but being too explicit in this case should not hurt.

Comment: Ok, thank you Guru. That makes sense. I will be able to accept your answer in about 4 minutes.

Comment: @David.Warwick was glad to help. Added some more info and docs.